# Passing data between two fragments with listview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tablayout using fragments and viewpager. Now in my second tab, I have this layout.
[image]

In the left, I have a fragment loaded, ListPlacesFragment. On the right is a different Fragment, DetailsPlacesFrament. When I click an item on the listview, I want to display it on the right fragment. I have used intents on activity, but i don't know how to pass the index of the list to the fragment on the right to display the appropriate details. Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that this is your `Activity` that contains `DetailsPlacesFragment`

```
================================================================
|                   |                                          |
|    ListView       |        FrameLayout                       |
|                   |                                          |
================================================================
```

In your `ListView`, set the adapter to something like this

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        displayDetailsPlacesFragment(position);
    }
}
```

and for the replaceable fragments in your `Activity`,

```
public void displayDetailsPlacesFragment(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = DetailsPlacesFragment.newInstance(position);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);  // FrameLayout id
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

and for your `DetailsPlacesFragment`, you define it by passing the `position` of the list item

```
public class DetailsPlacesFragment extends Fragment {
    public static DetailsPlacesFragment newInstance(int position) {
        DetailsPlacesFragment fragment = new DetailsPlacesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle icicle) {
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");  // use this position for specific list item
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, icicle);
    }
}
```

Comment: will this work on a tab layout that uses fragment and viewpager?

Comment: the idea of listview and pageradapter applies when dynamically replacing a fragment

Answer (score 0):

You should use your Activity as a mediator between the two fragments. What I would do is create an interface that the activity will implement like PlaceClickListener:

```
public interface PlaceClickListener{
    public void onPlaceClicked(int index);
}
```

In your activity, you have to implement it:

```
class MainActivity implements PlaceClickListener {

    /* other code */

    public void onPlaceClicked(int index){
        /* call function for detail fragment here */
    }
}
```

Then in your list fragment do something such as this when you click on an item:

```
((PlaceClickListener)getActivity()).onPlaceClicked(int index);
```

Then you can create a public method in the right fragment that you use the index to send the details to.

Comment: I'm sorry bro, can you give me an idea how to implement interface?

Comment: I have a problem. I already implemented ActionBarTab.listener. I can't implement the interface.

Comment: You can implement as many interfaces as you want. Just say "implements Interface1, Interface2 {"