# How to displaying item details in fragment from listview click

Tags: android, android-fragments

anyone know how to display details item in other fragment detail when everytime im click item from listview? and how to set them? and anyone have an example for this?
[image]
in listview only show : 
**- Nama, gambar1, tipe, mainmuscle, othermuscle, alat, rating on details** fragment i want to show : 
-Nama, gambar1, tipe, mainmuscle, othermuscle, alat, rating, **deskripsi, gambar2, gambar3, gambar4**

here my code :

Fragment.java

```
    public class AbdominalFragment extends Fragment {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = AbdominalFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http.......";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public AbdominalFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("tipe").equals("abdominal")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                        exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));
                                        exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("tipe"));
                                        exercise.setMainmuscle(obj.getString("mainmuscle"));
                                        exercise.setAlat(obj.getString("alat"));
                                        exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("othermuscle"));
                                        exercise.setRating(obj.getDouble("rating"));


                                        // adding exercise to exercise array
                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for onitemclick?

Comment: yes it's , itemonclick listview and open detail fragment for everytime item on listview clicked

Comment: As you using listview in fragment, right? Then on itemclick you can show a custom dialog with all the details you want to show.

Comment: yes i am, can you give an example ?

Comment: Onitemclick is what you use for listview items when clicked. Don't use findviewbyid for the click because you have many rows using the same id use findviewbytag and assign unique values to each tag http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event

Comment: if its get item onclick and shown on dialog, how about show into another fragment?

Comment: I have activity with ListFragment data from api and if click on item pass id for details api and then load detail fragment on that.Single activity with ListFragment and then after Details Fragment please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

make your fragment `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

```
public class AbdominalFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```

now **onClick**

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // Create custom dialog object
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            // Include dialog.xml file
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // layout of your dialog
            // Set dialog title
            dialog.setTitle("Detail");

            // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
            text.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getNama());
            // similar add statements for other details 
            dialog.show();

    }
```

layout for dialog **dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: already try your code,but nothing happen when im clicked item on listview

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(this); add this line in your code as shown in my answer

Comment: hmm its work, but its like dialog box, how to show on another fragment?

Comment: I think it is complication as , **onClick** first you have to **detach**  `AbdominalFragment` Fragment and **attack** another fragment with details. Just improve your `dialog.xml` so that Dialog looks good.

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually i want to represent item on listview when click like my example images i give on the first post,

Comment: Instead of "show on another fragment?" you can start new Activity via Intent method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110788/discussion-between-vishwesh-jainkuniya-and-f-x).

Comment: Hey , if its using Dialog box, how to im implement not using dialog box, but using fragement?

Comment: @F_X you can use Activity instead of fragment. So if you click on item on listview, it will start new Activity(say Activity2) with the details you want to show. You can pass details to Activity2 via **Bundle** or **Intent** method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `onCreate()`:

```
ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) {
            ArrayList clickedItem = exerciseList.get(position);
            //Here you can hadle your Views....
        }
});
```

Comment: can you explain to handle view on their? sorry guys im really" bad for code, but im try

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use interface to send call back to the activity that holds your AbdominalFragment from OnItemClickListener of ListView.

And according to that your activity can replace the AbdominalFragment with Details Fragment.

For communicating with activity see the below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: can you give an example i can try?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the Listfragment and overrride the onListItemClicked method.

like this,

```
public class AbdominalFragment extends ListFragment {

String[] MONTHS = { "jan", "feb", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july",
        "august", "sep", "octo", "nov", "dec" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            MONTHS);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "selected month :" + MONTHS[position],
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for answer, can you help implement thoose using my code?

Comment: hey, thanks for answer, can you help implement thoose using my code?

Comment: actually i want looks like a images i give on my post, so when item in listview clicked, they will move into another fragment for show details the items i click

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648825/passing-data-between-two-fragments-with-listview